# str performance in python

Tags: python, string, performance, python-3.x, python-2.7

While profiling a piece of python code (`python 2.6` up to `3.2`), I discovered that the
`str` method to convert an object (in my case an integer) to a string is almost an order of magnitude slower than using string formatting.

Here is the benchmark

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer('str(100000)').timeit()
0.3145311339386332
>>> Timer('"%s"%100000').timeit()
0.03803517023435887
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?
Am I missing something?

Comment: And what about `'{}'.format(100000)`

Comment: That is the slowest but also the most flexible.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`'%s' % 100000` is evaluated by the compiler and is equivalent to a constant at run-time.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: str(100000))
  8           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (str)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (100000)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(lambda: '%s' % 100000)
  9           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ('100000')
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

`%` with a run-time expression is not (significantly) faster than `str`:

```
>>> Timer('str(x)', 'x=100').timeit()
0.25641703605651855
>>> Timer('"%s" % x', 'x=100').timeit()
0.2169809341430664
```

Do note that `str` is still slightly slower, as @DietrichEpp said, this is because `str` involves lookup and function call operations, while `%` compiles to a single immediate bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: str(x))
  9           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (str)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: '%s' % x)
 10           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%s')
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MODULO       
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Of course the above is true for the system I tested on (CPython 2.7); other implementations may differ.

Comment: Indeed this looks like the reason, I just tried myself and string formatting is just about 5% faster than `str`. Thanks for answer. No reason to change code everywhere :-)

Comment: To elaborate further: `str` is a name that can be rebound to something other than the string type, but string formatting - i.e. the `str.__mod__` method - cannot be replaced, which permits the compiler to do the optimization. The compiler doesn't do very much in the way of optimization, but it does more than you might think :)

Comment: ...and the lesson to learn here is: never use literals in tests like these!

Comment: This particular blog entry may interest you: http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/. It contains a chart of benchmarks for various string concatenation methods similar to what you have provided above.

Answer (score 16):

One reason that comes to mind is the fact that `str(100000)` involves a global lookup, but `"%s"%100000` does not.  The `str` global has to be looked up in the global scope.  This does not account for the entire difference:

```
>>> Timer('str(100000)').timeit()
0.2941889762878418
>>> Timer('x(100000)', 'x=str').timeit()
0.24904918670654297
```

As noted by **thg435**,

```
>>> Timer('"%s"%100000',).timeit()
0.034214019775390625
>>> Timer('"%s"%x','x=100000').timeit()
0.2940788269042969
```